# Animate Image on scroll on line in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I create this using bootstrap so that it's responsive? I want to animate the bicycle from start to end as someone scrolls the page. Also, How can I create this dotted line in bootstrap such that it's responsive too?

Any codepen which can help here?

```
col-6       col-6
image start--------------(at bottom of border)
col-6       col-6
image------
col-6       col-6
image  end--------
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to make your page play animation when some waypoint is triggered. [There you can read guide about waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/).

Or you also can go through [this guide](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/webpage-scrolling-animation-effects-css3-jquery/) and it could help you.

As alternative you can use [ScrollMagic plugin](http://scrollmagic.io/).

I hope you will find something useful for you.